# C++ not allowing me to use a private member variable in a public function

Tags: c++

I am trying to develop a game in C++. For some reason, I can't access and update other variables as the value of the private member variables within a member public function of the class. Why is this the case? The variables mentioned are the ones prefixed with `m_`. Is this something that is not allowed in C++? I thought this would be allowed!

**Player.cpp**

```
#include "Player.h"
#include "lib/json.hpp"

using namespace std;

void Player::createPlayer(std::string name, std::string playerFilePath)
{
    m_name = name;
    m_playerFilePath = playerFilePath;

    json j;
    j["name"] = m_name;
    j["health"] = 100;
    j["levelOn"] = 1;
    j["damageDone"] = 10;

    std::string dataString = j.dump();
    std::string filename = playerFilePath + m_name + ".json";
    std::ofstream out(filename);
    out << dataString;
    out.close();

    cout << "Savegame file " << filename << " created" << endl;
}

void Player::loadPlayerData(std::string playerFilePath)
{
    std::ifstream t(playerFilePath);
    std::string str ((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t)),
                     std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

    auto j = json::parse(str);

    m_name = j["name"];
    m_health = j["health"];
    m_levelOn = j["levelOn"];
    m_damageDone = j["damageDone"];

    cout << "Player data loaded" << endl;

}

void Player::levelUp() 
{
    m_levelOn++;
    m_health += 10;
    m_damageDone += 5;
}


void savePlayerData()
{    
    std::ifstream t(m_playerFilePath);
    std::string str ((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t)),
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

    auto j = json::parse(str);

    j["name"] = m_name;
    j["health"] = m_health;
    j["levelOn"] = m_levelOn;
    j["damageDone"] = m_damageDone;

    std::string stringToWrite = j.dump();

    std::string filename = m_playerFilePath + m_name + ".json";
    std::ofstream out(filename);
    out << stringToWrite;
    out.close();

    cout << "Game saved" << endl;
}
```

**Player.h**

```
#pragma once

#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

#include <fstream>
#include "Enemy.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <streambuf>
#include "lib/json.hpp"

using json = nlohmann::json;

class Player {
    private:
        int m_health;
        int m_damageDone;
        int m_levelOn;
        std::string m_playerFilePath;
        std::string m_name;
    public:
        void createPlayer(std::string name, std::string playerFilePath);
        void dealDamage();
        void takeDamage();
        void levelUp();
        std::string getPlayerFilePath();
        void loadPlayerData(std::string playerFilePath);
        void savePlayerData();
};

#endif
```

**The g++ error message**

```
Player.cpp: In function ‘void savePlayerData()’:
Player.cpp:53:21: error: ‘m_playerFilePath’ was not declared in this scope
     std::ifstream t(m_playerFilePath);
                     ^
Player.cpp:59:17: error: ‘m_name’ was not declared in this scope
     j["name"] = m_name;
                 ^
Player.cpp:60:19: error: ‘m_health’ was not declared in this scope
     j["health"] = m_health;
                   ^
Player.cpp:61:20: error: ‘m_levelOn’ was not declared in this scope
     j["levelOn"] = m_levelOn;
                    ^
Player.cpp:62:23: error: ‘m_damageDone’ was not declared in this scope
     j["damageDone"] = m_damageDone;
                       ^
Player.cpp:66:28: error: ‘m_playerFilePath’ was not declared in this scope
     std::string filename = m_playerFilePath + m_name + ".json";
```

Comment: Any error message?

Comment: Edit your question and add the text error message. If this is Visual Studio please copy the text from the Output Tab (not the Errors Tab).

Comment: @tkausl The G++ error message for all of them was: 'Error: m_variablename was not declared in this scope`

Comment: ***Is this something that is not allowed in C++?*** It is absolutely allowed. private variables would be pointless if you could not use them.

Comment: @drescherjm added the error message

Comment: The answer is correct. You missed the Player:: before savePlayerData() so you created a free function that has nothing to do with Player.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `savePlayerData` doesn't belong to the `Player` class. Insert `Player::` before your `savePlayerData` function.